# I have an error trying to create a new excel sheet in a SSIS project

Tags: ssis

When I try to add  a new excel sheet to my excel destination connection. I the following error: 
Unexpected error from external database controller (1309). (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)

[ScreenCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dACy.png)

Comment: Can you give a better description of the thing you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. that error means that the Excel file being currently used by another process/user (or just renaming orphaned in memory).

So just with closing the file is solve.